# client-server communication emulation in c using pipes

Tags: c

I want to emulate a flight ticket reservation system using Inter-Proccess Communication **Pipes exclusively**

I want to have 10 clients which interact with the main server(**parent proccess**) using pipes.

The clients(**child proccesses**) are supposed to generate a random number from 0-9 which is supposed to be a flight id and an amount of seats between 1-3.Then they will pass the above request in the client and after some checks they will be informed if the server can hold them seats(**success/failure**).

My issue here is that the 10 child proccesses do indeed generate random flight id's and seat numbers,but the parent procedure will only hold on to the first generated flight id **10 times**.

It is the very first time i use pipes and file descriptors,so there might be a lot of mistakes,if you can spot them and help me figure this out it would be much appreciated!

If you need further explanation on any command,tell me,there are a lot of variables that i use for sums and checks.(**This is only a part of the program associated with the IPC,if you want me to have the full program editted please reach out**)

```
for(j=0;j<=9;j++)
{
    pid=fork();
    if(pid<0)
    {
        perror("Error");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(pid==0)
    {
        for(i=0;i<=9;i++)
        {
            close(fd1[j][0]);
            close(fd2[j][0]);
            seats = (rand() % 3)+1 ;
            id= (rand()% 10);
            printf("id %d seats %d\n",id,seats);
            write(fd1[j][1],&id,sizeof(id));
            write(fd2[j][1],&seats,sizeof(seats));
            close(fd1[j][1]);
            close(fd2[j][1]);
            read(fd1[j][0],&good,sizeof(good));
            if(good)
            {
                printf("success\n");
                read(fd2[j][0],&flights[id].price,sizeof(flights[id].price));
                close(fd2[j][0]);
            }
            else
            {   
                printf("failure\n");
            }
            close(fd1[j][0]);}
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        if(check==0){
            struct fl flights[10]= 
            {
                {0,(rand() % 5)+1,"Athens","Paris",20},
                {1,(rand() % 5)+1,"London","Madrid",25},
                {2,(rand() % 5)+1,"Moscow","Kiev",17},
                {3,(rand() % 5)+1,"Manchester","Munchen",23},
                {4,(rand() % 5)+1,"Budapest","Torino",15},
                {5,(rand() % 5)+1,"Rome","Thessaloniki",21},
                {6,(rand() % 5)+1,"Amsterdam","Lisbon",13},
                {7,(rand() % 5)+1,"Sofia","Tallinn",10},
                {8,(rand() % 5)+1,"Vienna","Bucharest",22},
                {9,(rand() % 5)+1,"Copenhagen","Minsk",26}
            }; 
            check=1;}
        for(j=0;j<=9;j++)
        {
            close(fd1[j][1]);
            close(fd2[j][1]);
            read(fd1[j][0],&id,sizeof(id));
            read(fd2[j][0],&seats,sizeof(seats));
            sun_krathseis=sun_krathseis+1;
            sunolikes[id]=sunolikes[id]+1;
            if(flights[id].available_seats>=seats)
            {
                kerdh=kerdh+flights[id].price;
                flights[id].available_seats=flights[id].available_seats-seats;
                epit[id]=epit[id]+1;
                epitux_krat=epitux_krat+1;
                good=1;
            }
            else
            {
                apot[id]=apot[id]+1;
                good=0;
            }
            write(fd1[j][1],&good,sizeof(good));
            if(good){
                write(fd2[j][1],&flights[id].price,sizeof(flights[id].price));
                close(fd2[j][1]);
            }
            close(fd1[j][1]);  
        }
        waitpid=wait(NULL);
        if(waitpid==-1)
        {
            perror("Error");
        }
        printf("Parent proccess ended \n");
    }
}

}
```

Comment: The child seem to be closing the fds in the first iteration of the loop.  They can't write to them in the 2nd iteration if they've already been closed!  Add error checking to the `writes` and you'll probably see `invalid file descriptor` errors.

Comment: But....? Why is the child exiting in the first iteration of the loop?  What's the point of looping if you exit in the first iteration?  Something is strange with your logic.

Comment: Maybe my eyes are shot, but `for() { ... } else {}` is a syntax error.  It would help if you would use an indentation style that is more readable.  Single space indentation is not a good idea.

Comment: so i should avoid closing the fds in the child?which fds tho the read or the write ones?

Comment: If the child writes to the parent, the child closes the read end and keeps the write end open.

Comment: It would be helpful to use more meaningful names for your pipes. Instead of `fd1` and `fd2`, use `pipe_to_child` and `pipe_from_child`.

Comment: fd1 is for the id value pass and fd2 is for the seats value pass is that wrong?

Comment: what i want is:
the child requests a flight id and a number of seats(write)
parent will check if there is enough seats available(read)
parent will inform child if the request is successfull(write)
child will read the results from the parent(read)

is my implementation that wrong?